# R Categorising data using multiple If() statements

Tags: r, if-statement, categories

I have created a table with football players and specific positions. I would now like to also categorise each player into their general positions (GPosition) i.e. Goalkeeper, Defender, Midfielder and Forward. Sorry if these seems rudimentary, but I am very new to R

Part of my Data is below:

```
            Player      Position  GPosition
1  Thibaut Courtois       Keeper  Goalkeeper
2   Willy Caballero       Keeper  Goalkeeper
9           Eduardo       Keeper  Goalkeeper
17      Matej Delac       Keeper  Goalkeeper
19       David Luiz  Centre-Back  Goalkeeper
22  Antonio Rüdiger  Centre-Back  Goalkeeper
```

I have tried using If() or Which() statements but have run into a few issues. When I run my code all GPositions run as GoalKeeper rather than other classifications. I am also unsure if using th "==" is the correct code to be using for this.

Part of my code:

```
PlayerPositions$GPosition <- if(PlayerPositions$Position == "Keeper") {
  PlayerPositions$GPosition <- "Goalkeeper"
} else if (PlayerPositions$Position == "Centre-Back"){
  PlayerPositions$GPosition <- "Defender"
} else if (PlayerPositions$Position == "Left-Back"){
  PlayerPositions$GPosition <- "Defender"
} else if (PlayerPositions$Position == "Right-Back"){
  PlayerPositions$GPosition <- "Defender"
```

And so on.... until last line:

```
} else if (PlayerPositions$Position == "Right Wing") {
  PlayerPositions$GPosition <- "Forward"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested `ifelse`s instead of `if` and `else`. Here's why and how:

```
x <- c(1,2,3)
if (x==2) print("hello") else print("world")
# [1] "world"
# Warning message:
#   In if (x == 2) print("hello") else print("world") :
#   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

The condition here is the result of `x==2`, which is `FALSE, TRUE, FALSE`. The warning disappears if you just use one element of `x`:

```
if (x[1]==2) print("hello") else print("world")
# [1] "world"
```

Now, using `ifelse` instead, you get three values - one for each element of `x`:

```
ifelse(x==2, "hello", "world")
# [1] "world" "hello" "world"

ifelse(x==2, "hello", ifelse(x==1, "HELLO", "world"))
# [1] "HELLO" "hello" "world"
```

So in your case:

```
PlayerPositions$GPosition <- 
  ifelse(PlayerPositions$Position == "Keeper", "Goalkeeper", 
    ifelse(PlayerPositions$Position %in% paste(c("Center", "Left", "Right"), "Back", sep="-"), "Defender", "Forward"))
```

Comment: Thanks Luke, this is great. If I then want to add another Position e.g. "Sweeper" into the Defender GPosition how would I do that?

Comment: @ggEngland `ifelse(Position == ""Center-Back", "Defender", ifelse(Position == "Sweeper", "Defender", "Forward")` etc. - you can nest as many `ifelse`s as you wish.

Comment: Thank you Luke, You have really helped

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using `case_when` from `dplyr` instead of multiple ifelse statements